# jenkins pipeline stage view does not show sub project stage build progress

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

i am trying to run a jenkins job which calls other jobs, which i do by doing the following:

```
node {
    stage ('Building Sub Project1') {
        res = build job: 'Sub Project1'

        stage ('Building Sub Project2') {
            build job: 'Sub Project2', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'hash', value: res.buildVariables.hash]]
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately i see only the 2 stages that i've defined in this project. Is there a way to visualise the "sub" project stages that are being build in the background?