# Jenkins:Pipeline combine several pipelines in one

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

Is there a way to combine two pipelines in one job with proper visualization?

*For example*: **build** job has it's pipeline in scm and **publish** job has it's own pipeline in different scm.

But it would be nice to have both pipelines in one run.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think so.

it seems to show just the stage of the parent pipeline when you use `build`.

:|

see also [jenkins pipeline stage view does not show sub project stage build progress](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44723911/6090676).

you might submit a feature request.